# multiple permission togather facebook

Tags: facebook

I am using Login with Facebook [using this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/ios-6/)

where i can open session with

```
NSArray *permissions =  [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"email", nil];

[FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:permissions
                                   allowLoginUI:YES
                              completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState status, NSError *error) {
                                  /* handle success + failure in block */
                              }];
```

which ask user for permission to read email address of facebook user.
Now i want my application to ask user for "publish_actions" permission together means once user allow to read email address, it will ask for "publish_actions".

how can i do this??

Comment: Capital letters evade you...